# javascript / узнать цвет по отенку

Tags: javascript

У меня есть разный диапазон цвета в hex (Например желтый:  #fbfa73, #fbfd3f), как при помощи js можно определить что это именно желтый цвет?

Comment: Вы же уже об этом третий раз спрашиваете

Comment: Нет, Первый. А вы бы лучше ответ дали)

Comment: А я и давал, и суть с тех пор не изменилась

Comment: А, понял про что вы, там вопрос на python, я не знаю как сделать это на js

Comment: По мимо этого у цвета #fbfd3f hue выше 60, чем в таблице, которую вы приводили http://www.workwithcolor.com/yellow-color-hue-range-01.htm (Хотя это явно желтый), и как тогда определить что есть желтый

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю работает ли оно, но вроде работает как-то.
Переводим hex в rgb, затем

```
Пусть r1, g1, b1 - Значения целевого цвета, а
r2, g2, b2 - второго цвета
```

Находим x1, x2, x3:

```
x1 = модуль(r1 - r2) / 255, также находим x2, x3 для g1, g2 и b1, b2

И схожесть цвета в процентах тогда = (x1 + x2 + x3) / 3 * 100
```

Вроде быстро протестил и все нормально. Цвет выбираем по наименьшему проценту
Для цвета 255, 255, 0 и 251, 253, 63 (hex #fbfd3f) разница будет 9%

Comment: Проверил разницу между желтым и фиолетовым (rgb 251, 253, 63, 187 46 255) получилось 10%. И как понять что это не желтый цвет?

Comment: Если даже у желтого может быть разница 9% )

Comment: Я не отрицаю что способ плох, но может у вас ошибка есть? Могу код глянуть. Я сейчас в свой вставил эти 2 значения и получил 60%

Comment: код 
r1 = 251
g1 = 253
b1 = 63

r2 = 187
g2 = 46
b2 = 255


x1 = (r1 - r2) / 255
x2 = (g1 - g2) / 255
x3 = (b1 -b2) / 255

console.log((x1 + x2 + x3) / 3 * 100)

Comment: Перед тем как в x1, x2, x3 делить на 255, результат в модуль оберните. В js например x1 = Math.abs((r1 - r2)) / 255, также и с x2, x3 Вот так. Без модуля 10% получается, я проверил

Comment: А почему способ может быть плох?

Comment: Помогло добавить модули? Ну, я не особо в эту тему углублялся, но предположительно должны быть ошибки, можно протестить на большем количестве образцов